# How can I split a large file csv file (7GB) in Python

Tags: python, csv, split

I have a 7GB `csv` file which I'd like to split into smaller chunks, so it is readable and faster for analysis in Python on a notebook. I would like to grab a small set from it, maybe 250MB, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 49):

You don't need Python to split a csv file. Using your shell:

```
$ split -l 100 data.csv
```

Would split `data.csv` in chunks of 100 lines.

Comment: Note: this DOES NOT keep the header intact for each file. Just incase you want the header fields for every chunk.

Comment: Not fool-proof for csv files. If there are newlines inside long text quote escaped values, rows might get split between two files.

Comment: Last argument can be added to prefix files with useful name `split -l 100 data.csv data_split_`

Comment: And what I need to do with your answer if I have the same question and getting here from google? The question is: "How to split huge file by Python?" (**not by CMD or bush or everything else...) :(

Answer (score 33):

I had to do a similar task, and used the pandas package:

```
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('bigfile.csv', chunksize=500000)):
    chunk.to_csv('chunk{}.csv'.format(i), index=False)
```

Comment: I don't think this solution is good. I have a 2 Gb (16m rows) and pandas is unable to handle it in memory. Chunking doesn't mean you don't load the whole df into memory (RAM), it just means you read it with the number of lines specified in `chunksize` at once.

Comment: This is a great answer. But note that this adds an extra index column to the original csv.

Comment: "this adds an extra index column to the original csv." - This has now been fixed by adding Index=False.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a little python script I used to split a file `data.csv` into several CSV part files. The number of part files can be controlled with `chunk_size` (number of lines per part file).

The header line (column names) of the original file is copied into every part CSV file.

It works for big files because it reads one line at a time with `readline()` instead of loading the complete file into memory at once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    chunk_size = 9998  # lines

    def write_chunk(part, lines):
        with open('data_part_'+ str(part) +'.csv', 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(header)
            f_out.writelines(lines)

    with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        header = f.readline()
        lines = []
        for line in f:
            count += 1
            lines.append(line)
            if count % chunk_size == 0:
                write_chunk(count // chunk_size, lines)
                lines = []
        # write remainder
        if len(lines) > 0:
            write_chunk((count // chunk_size) + 1, lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @GooDeeJAY - this is a good answer and the code is self explanatory.  Good code can "do the talking" without an extensive narrative.

Comment: @Powers I totally agree with you. However, I also believe (this community thought me) that there should be some kind of explanatory text above the code. I see that he already edited his post and added some explanatory text. Seems like that time I forgot to 'Follow' the post, so didn't get notified when he edited his post, to delete my comment.

Answer (score 6):

This graph shows the runtime difference of the different approaches outlined by other posters (on an 8 core machine when splitting a 2.9 GB file with 11.8 million rows of data into ~290 files).

[image]

The shell approach is from Thomas Orozco, Python approach s from Roberto, Pandas approach is from Quentin Febvre and here's the Dask snippet:

```py
ddf = dd.read_csv("../nyc-parking-tickets/Parking_Violations_Issued_-_Fiscal_Year_2015.csv", blocksize=10000000, dtype=dtypes)
ddf.to_csv("../tmp/split_csv_dask")
```

I'd recommend Dask for splitting files, even though it's not the fastest, because it's the most flexible solution (you can write out different file formats, perform processing operations before writing, easily modify compression formats, etc.).  The Pandas approach is almost as flexible, but cannot perform processing on the entire dataset (like sorting the entire dataset before writing).

Bash / native Python filesystem operations are clearly quicker, but that's not what I'm typically looking for when I have a large CSV.  I'm typically interested in splitting large CSVs into smaller Parquet files, for performant, production data analyses.  I don't usually care if the actually splitting takes a couple minutes more.  I'm more interested in splitting accurately.

I wrote a blog post that discusses this in more detail.  You can probably Google around and find the post.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) on `file` objects (the object returned by `open(filename)` - you can choose to `read` a specified number of bytes, or use `readline` to work through one line at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import csv

divisor = 10

outfileno = 1
outfile = None

with open('big.csv', 'r') as infile:
    for index, row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile)):
        if index % divisor == 0:
            if outfile is not None:
                outfile.close()
            outfilename = 'big-{}.csv'.format(outfileno)
            outfile = open(outfilename, 'w')
            outfileno += 1
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This does indeed split the CSV however there are blank rows in between each row in the outputs csvs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jonrsharpe readline should be able to read one line at a time even for big files.

If you are dealing with big csv files might I suggest using [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). I often use it for the same purpose and always find it awesome (and fast). Takes a bit of time to get used to idea of DataFrames. But once you get over that it speeds up large operations like yours massively.

Hope it helps.

Comment: pandas is actually a very poor solution to handle big csv files as they can only truly work with the data that can be stored in your RAM at one time. Would recommend other libraries such as Dask. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-deep-dive-into-dask-dataframes-7455d66a5bc5

Answer (score 1):

here is my code which might help

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import uuid


class FileSettings(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name, row_size=100):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.row_size = row_size


class FileSplitter(object):

    def __init__(self, file_settings):
        self.file_settings = file_settings

        if type(self.file_settings).__name__ != "FileSettings":
            raise Exception("Please pass correct instance ")

        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.file_settings.file_name,
                              chunksize=self.file_settings.row_size)

    def run(self, directory="temp"):

        try:os.makedirs(directory)
        except Exception as e:pass

        counter = 0

        while True:
            try:
                file_name = "{}/{}_{}_row_{}_{}.csv".format(
                    directory,  self.file_settings.file_name.split(".")[0], counter, self.file_settings.row_size, uuid.uuid4().__str__()
                )
                df = next(self.df).to_csv(file_name)
                counter = counter + 1
            except StopIteration:
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error:",e)
                break

        return True


def main():
    helper =  FileSplitter(FileSettings(
        file_name='sample1.csv',
        row_size=10
    ))
    helper.run()

main()
```

Comment: How could I avoid `the number order column` at first col?

Comment: Please change to `df = next(self.df).to_csv(file_name, index=False)` to avoid writing row names (index) at first col.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of wanting to split by rough boundaries in bytes, the newest datapoints being the bottom-most ones and wanting to put the newest datapoints in the first file:

```
from pathlib import Path
    
TEN_MB = 10000000
FIVE_MB = 5000000

def split_file_into_chunks(path, chunk_size=TEN_MB):
    path = str(path)
    output_prefix = path.rpartition('.')[0]
    output_ext = path.rpartition('.')[-1]

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        seek_positions = []
        for x, line in enumerate(f):
            if not x:
                header = line
            seek_positions.append(f.tell())

        part = 0
        last_seek_pos = seek_positions[-1]
        for seek_pos in reversed(seek_positions):
            if last_seek_pos-seek_pos >= chunk_size:
                with open(f'{output_prefix}.arch.{part}.{output_ext}', 'wb') as f_out:
                    f.seek(seek_pos)
                    f_out.write(header)
                    f_out.write(f.read(last_seek_pos-seek_pos))

                last_seek_pos = seek_pos
                part += 1

        with open(f'{output_prefix}.arch.{part}.{output_ext}', 'wb') as f_out:
            f.seek(0)
            f_out.write(f.read(last_seek_pos))

    Path(path).rename(path+'~')
    Path(f'{output_prefix}.arch.0.{output_ext}').rename(path)
    Path(path+'~').unlink()
```