# Alternatives to Python for large data

Tags: python, pandas

This is indeed a broad topic. As a rookie in Pandas, I would find it useful to have a post on Stackoverflow where we can describe and comment with regards to the different alternatives there are to handle data that is not loadable in regular computers (I will draw the line here on 16Gb of RAM). I am currently learning how to easily process about 50Gb.

So far, I have chrisb and Noobie have mentioned Dask as a potential alternative. Ideally, I would like to perform similar operations as the ones I would typically perform on Pandas.

I have read around the forum and found some methods to divide the cvs file into more manageable 1Gb files that I can load and handle separately using read_csv. For example, this question [How can I split a large file csv file (7GB) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033861/how-can-i-split-a-large-file-csv-file-7gb-in-python) shows how to split a large cvs file.

1) However, how would one operate efficiently typical pandas functions like groupby with several separate csv files without reading them all into memory?

2) I have seen mentions of other python libraries that address large datasets. For example, some posts in this community refer to HDF5 and Blazer as alternatives for large data handling. How would that fit into what i would like to do? what would be an example of using these or other libraries to perform common pandas operations?

3) What would be a suggested path to follow in order to deal with this large data?

Thank you and I appreciate your help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 3) What would be a suggested path to follow in order to deal with this
>   large data?

Answer: buy additional RAM so that your total amount of RAM is larger than your dataset.

Pandas was designed for in-RAM computation, and its really good at it. Unfortunately, given the large size of your data relative to the tiny amount of RAM you have, you will find yourself struggling more than needed. Forget Pandas here if you cannot afford more RAM.

Other options are Hadoop, Amazon EC2, Dask or Google cloud computing.

Comment: Depending on the structure of the data and what the analysis is `dask` could handle this on a single 8gb machine without too much pain.

Comment: yes maybe. check out the documentation. dask can also use distributed machine computing.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your replies. How is the migration from pandas to dask?

Comment: https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial